# Mobile programming

Tags: java-me, mobile, nokia

I have Nokia 2700.
On which programming language i can develop programs? Only Java ME?
Which PL is best choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nokia 2700 [is a](http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/2700_classic/#Technical_Specs_Developer_Platform) *Series 40 5th Edition, Feature Pack 1* phone, so you can develop in anything supported by that platform. Unfortunately, that *anything* [is limited](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/Platforms/Series_40_Platform_SDKs/) to [Java ME](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Events/Training_and_Educational_Events/eLearning.xhtml#java) and [Flash lite](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a95e7aa-c231-401f-adc1-9166d53d1a7a.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to experiment a bit, you could use Hecl ( http://www.hecl.org ), perhaps via HeclBuilder ( http://www.heclbuilder.com ), which is built on top of Java ME.